# Login to EUC Dashboard works via CloudFront URL but not via User Portal

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml, saml-2.0

I am creating an EUC Dashboard in AWS by following this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/de/getting-started/hands-on/euc-dashboard/).

SSO is the IdP and a Cognito User Pool is the SP.
I created a user in SSO who can sign-in and see the Dashboard via the direct CloudFront URL.

When trying to login via the User Portal (clicking on the Dashboard-App in the User Portal) with this link `https://d-NUMBER.awsapps.com/start/#/saml/default/dashboard/ins-NUMBER`
I get this response from Cognito:

`https://APP-NAME.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/error?error=Invalid_samlResponse_or_relayState_from_identity_provider`

By looking at the request that is send I can see that the RelayState is empty and the SAML-Response contains my e-mail as expected.

How do the two types of sign-in differ and why doesn't the User Portal method work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this:

In the configuration for the SSO application at Application properties for Application start URL I added the CloudFront URL: `https://ID.cloudfront.net/index.html`

This is probably only a workaround to the issue but it works.